# How to add a vs2005 .tlb reference to a vb6 app

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, .net-2.0

Error referencing vs2005 c#
file(.tlb extension) in 
vb6 application.

error message:
Can't create activeX object

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your app [callable by COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w29wacsy(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you did not compile the c# library yourself on the same computer, you will need to register it with [regtlib](http://www.google.de/search?q=regtlib&hl=de&meta=).

In my experience if it does not show up in the Project|Reference Dialog by itself, don't bother adding it manually. Something went wrong before and it won't help to add it manually.